# OpenCV findChessboardCorners very slow

Tags: performance, opencv, feature-detection

dose anybody know why is **cv::findChessboardCorners** horribly slow on all images with more than one mega-pixel ( > 1 000 000 pixles ).

As a workaround I down-sample my images to fit this bound, but I would like to know if it can be solved more "elegantly".

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Haven't dug into the reasons - I wrote a much faster square finder from scratch.

The circleGrid provides a better result and is much faster, it uses the new BlobDetector interface.

Comment: it's in the examples dir in  opencv - stereocalib.cpp (IIRC)